# How to parse command line arguments in Python?

Tags: python, arguments, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [What's the best way to grab/parse command line arguments passed to a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063/whats-the-best-way-to-grab-parse-command-line-arguments-passed-to-a-python-scrip)

I would like to be able to parse command line arguments in my Python 2.6 program.

Ideally, I want to be able to handle these cases:

```
# Show some help
./myprogram --help

# These are equivalent
./myprogram --block=1
./myprogram -b 1

# This means verbose, and twice as verbose:
./myprogram -v
./myprogram -vv
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check out the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module (or [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) for older Python versions).
Note that `argparse`/`optparse` are newer, better replacements for `getopt`, so if you're new to this they're the recommended option. From the `getopt` docs:

> Note The getopt module is a parser for command line options whose API is designed to be familiar to users of the C getopt() function. Users who are unfamiliar with the C getopt() function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the argparse module instead.

Comment: And by "older Python versions", he means every version that was released more than 8 days ago.

Comment: @Forest - shhhh, we're in the future now! ;)

Comment: And as time goes by, this answer just gets more and more correct.

Answer (score 3):

Python has argument processing built in, with the [`getopt`](http://diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/command_line_arguments.html) module.

It can handle long and short forms of arguments as well as "naked" and parameterised versions (`--help` versus `--num=7`).

For your specific use cases (with a little more), you'd probably be looking at something like:

```
opts,args = getopt.getopt(argv,"b:vVh",["block=", "verbose", "very-verbose", "help"])
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head if it allows multi-character single-hyphen variants like `-vv`. I'd just use `-v` and `-V` myself to make my life easier.

Answer (score 1):

A better option than that link is the modules OptParse or GetOpt, and depending on which version of Python you're using, the newest ones..2.7, and 3.1.2, have an even newer module built in. The documentation on the official python.org reference has a very informative set of documentation and examples for those modules. If you go to python.org and just do a quick search for OptParse or GetOpt, you'll have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

[optfunc](http://github.com/simonw/optfunc) is an interesting little module. It's great if you want to quickly write a little script. For larger things I would go with [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) as others wrote.

Answer (score -5):

There might be a better way but I would just uses sys.argv and put in conditionals wherever needed i.e.

```
if '--v' or '--vv' in sys.argv :
    print 'verbose message'
```