# Most pythonic way of accepting arguments using optparse

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse, optparse

I currently have a python file that utilizes sys.argv[1] to accept a string at the command line. It then performs operations on that string and then returns the modified string to the command line.

I would like to implement a batch mode option in which I can provide a file of strings (one per line, fwiw) and have it return to the command line so that I can redirect the output doing something like

```
$ python script.py -someflag file.txt > modified.txt
```

while still retaining the current capabilities.

I am only running 2.6, so argparse is not an option. The tutorials I have seen either use argparse, getopt, or delve into examples that are too complex/don't apply.

What is the best way to check the input and act appropriately?

Comment: argparse is still an option, it's just not built into 2.6. You can still install it like any 3rd party package (for example, `pip install argparse`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[argparse](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse) is still an option, it's just not built into 2.6. You can still install it like any 3rd party package (for example, using `easy_install argparse`).

An example of code for this would be:

```
import sys
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="script.py")
p.add_argument("-s", dest="string")
p.add_argument("-f", dest="infile")

args = p.parse_args()

if args.infile == None and args.string == None:
    print "Must be given either a string or a file"
    sys.exit(1)
if args.infile != None and args.string != None:
    print "Must be given either a string or a file, not both"
    sys.exit(1)
if args.infile:
    # process the input file one string at a time
if args.string:
    # process the single string
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that argparse was third-party before 2.7, and the code is an added bonus. I will likely accept this as soon as I get a chance to try it out :)

Comment: You're quite welcome. argparse is a very powerful and intuitive tool and I highly recommend it.

Comment: When testing against `None`, it is more pythonic to use `is` and `is not` to test for that value: `if args.infile is None and args.string is None:` and `if args.infile is not None and args.string is not None:`.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer here: [What's the best way to grab/parse command line arguments passed to a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063/whats-the-best-way-to-grab-parse-command-line-arguments-passed-to-a-python-scri/26910#26910)

As a shortcut, here's some sample code:

```
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option('-q', '--query',
    action="store", dest="query",
    help="query string", default="spam")

options, args = parser.parse_args()

print 'Query string:', options.query
```

Comment: **Note**: Using *optparse* is discouraged since python version 2.7. The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the *argparse* module. See [PEP 0389](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/) for more info.