# Running python commands in solaris os

Tags: python, solaris

I have one python file (abc.py) which include several commands like make directory, copy commands. I want to execute it  such like that,whenever I hit command for example  abc --makedir on console, it should make directory. makedir is function which is written in abc.py.

Comment: I had tried adding it in a path variable but it does not works.

Comment: Where is your code and what's the problem?

Comment: This sounds like you should use the shell, not Python.

Comment: The file name, including any extension, is how you invoke a script.  If you want the command to be named `abc` then the file should be named `abc`.  There is no requirement to have a `.py` extension on a Python script in Unix; in fact, for anything you want to use as a direct command, it's probably not a good idea.  Just make sure you give the file a proper shebang line like `#!/usr/bin/env python` on the very first line of the file, and make sure the file is executable, and that the directory it's in is on your `PATH`.

Comment: there is a python file named abc.py
and containing a function name makedir() which when called makes a new directory.
i want to execute as abc --makedir
it should make a new directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `abc.py` to `abc`.

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x abc
```

Then add this at the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

From command line (if `abc` is in python path):

```
#abc
```

To create a directory like you said , you should parse arguments passed to python script.

For example:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv)>1:
    if sys.argv[1] == '--makedir':
        makedir()
```

For more informations Look at this link [What's the best way to grab/parse command line arguments passed to a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063/whats-the-best-way-to-grab-parse-command-line-arguments-passed-to-a-python-scri)