# Pass the multiple arguments with variable name from PHP to PYTHON

Tags: php, python, arguments

I need to pass the argument with variable name from PHP to PYTHON.

here is my requirement in coding.

```
$output = shell_exec('python3 ActorArrayMatcher_FS2.py var1 = val1 & var2 = val2 & ... & varN = valN ');
print_r($output);
```

and how to receive in python

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Please share the knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`shell_exec()` is a bash (or other interpreter) call, so you'll need to structure your command as if you were running it on the command line:

```
$output = shell_exec('python3 ActorArrayMatcher_FS2.py var1=val1 var2=val2 varN=valN');
```

Things to keep in mind:

- `python3` must be executable by the user running your PHP script
- Ensure you escape any variable shell arguments via `escapeshellarg()` before passing them into `shell_exec()`
- The path to `ActorArrayMatcher_FS2.py` would be safer as an absolute path, and you'll need to ensure that the user running your PHP script has permissions for it

Comment: sorry. Did not understand what i am asking. how to pass the parameter with variable name and how to receive in python.
var1=val1 var2=val2 varN=valN  how to pass should like this and 
import sys
print(sys.argv)  receive like this

Comment: Does your python script receive the input variables from `sys.argv`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate over `sys.argv`, it is a list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys


def main():
    for a in sys.argv:
        print(a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For more elaborate argument parsing, I suggest you look at argument parsing libraries for Python; in no special order:

- [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)
- [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/)

Relevant SO question: [What's the best way to parse command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments)