# How to parse argparser arguments by value

Tags: python, argparse

Currently I am writing the script that accepts space separated arguments like this

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='foo 1.0')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--arch', help='specify the angle', nargs="+" choices=ch_list, required=True
```

I am passing either

```
+foo +bar +baz
```

or

```
-foo -bar -baz
```

or

```
foo bar baz
```

where `foo bar baz` are alphanum elements

What is the most elegant way of sorting arguments out?

Either all should have `+` sign or `-` sign or no sign at all, if arguments mix happened the script should throw the error and exit.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can't pass any of `-foo, -baz, -bar` as values. The hyphen will make ArgParse interpret it as an option flag and spew out an error.

2)

> What is the most elegant way of sorting arguments out?

You can have

```
ch_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', '+foo', '+bar', '+baz']
```

which would ensure nothing outside of that list is allowed, but it wouldn't prevent the user from entering a mix and match of the different formats say`./program --arch foo +baz +bar`.

To prevent that, you would need to validate the arguments yourself after `parse_args()`.

```
  args = parser.parse_args()
  l = args.arch if args.arch is not None else []
  if len(l):
    has_plus = lambda x : x[0] == '+'
    first_has_plus = has_plus(l[0])
    for x in l:
      if first_has_plus ^ has_plus(x):
        print("INVALID")
        return
    print("PASSED")
```