# Passing values from command line python

Tags: python, sys

I have a python function that requires several parameters. Something like:

```
def func(par1=1, par2=2, par3=3):
...
```

I want to make this callable from command line such as: `function.py par1=1 par2=2 par3=3`.

I was thinking of doing it something like this:

```
import sys

if sys.argv[0][0:4]=="par1":
   par1=int(sys.argv[0][5:])
else:
   par1=1
```

but it doesn't look very nice, as the user might pass just some parametrs, or they might pass it as `par1 =1` or `par1= 1` or `par1 = 1` so I would have to hard code with if-else all these possibilities. Is there a nicer, more professional solution? Thank you!

Comment: `function.py par1=1 par2=2 par3=3` violates expectations on UNIX commands. `function.py --par1=1 --par2=2 --par3=3` looks much better. Consult [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to parse command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `argparse` from the standard library

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--par1", type=int, default=1, help="This is the description")
opts = parser.parse_args()

print(opts.part1)
```

checkout the docs for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Amadan's comment, you probably want `function.py --par1=1 --par2=2 --par3=3` and not `function.py par1=1 par2=2 par3=3`

For the former, you can use

**function.py**

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--par1", default=11)
parser.add_argument("--par2", default=22)
parser.add_argument("--par3", default=33)
parser.add_argument("--par4", default=44)
opts = parser.parse_args()

print(opts.par1, opts.par2, opts.par3, opts.par4)
```

```sh
$ python function.py  # default values
11 22 33 44

$ python function.py --par1 99  # spaces are OK
99 22 33 44

$ python function.py --par1=99  # = are OK
99 22 33 44
```