# how can i send function parameters from terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I send the bellow to function parameters?

Example

```
[superuser@superuser deneme]$ myprogram.py --name=Jhon --surname=Wick --day=1
```

How can I do as I stated?
Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: argparse or fire are good options. See answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20063/4590385 . Also, in the future, search Stack Overflow more before posting your question. The title of your question with "python appended" will yield many answers in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use argparse module

```
import argparse

arg = argparse.ArgumentParser()
arg.add_argument('-n', '--name', required=True) 
arg.add_argument('-s', '--surname', required=True)
arg.add_argument('-d', '--day', required=True)
args = vars(arg.parse_args())

name, surname, day = args['name'], args['surname'], args['day']
```