# Python input a file using -f from command line on Windows

Tags: python, input, command, command-line-interface

I am trying to understand this side of the python where we execute Python from commandline and input a specific file or asking to perform specific task. Presently I wanted to input a file like this

```
# input a file 
c:>python main_file.py -f input1.txt
# output a file
c:>python main_file.py -o output1.txt
```

Comment: Are `-f` and `-o` standard command line arguments to `python` or just your `main_file.py` script?

Comment: @eugenhu Ok. If there are no such standard command-line arguments, please treat it just for my script.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking then, could you rephrase? Do you mean how to retrieve the arguments in your script, e.g. [sys.argv()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)?

Comment: @eugenhu My apologies. I have also no idea whether these are standard commands from Python. I just heard them. I was saying, if there are no such Python commands, please treat it just for my script (as If I have to design my script in such a way that it responds to `-f` or `-o` commands).

Comment: @eugenhu Can help me to figure out what I am searching is actually Python `invoke` commands? http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/0.12.1/getting_started.html

Comment: Alright I'm going to take a shot in the dark and say you're looking for help on how to parse command line arguments in python scripts, in this case have a look at [What's the best way to parse command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20063/8944057). The basics is to just look at the elements in `sys.argv`, for starters just have your `main_file.py` script be `print(sys.argv)` to see what it contains.

Comment: Not sure what Invoke is, but that's a third-party library that may or may not help you do what you want.

Comment: @eugenhu Thanks a lot for this potential suggestion. Without your help, I would have not known. Now I will try `sys.argv` and see if it can solve my issue.

Comment: @eugenhu can you take a look at my new q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577340/python-argparse-compare-input-and-default-file-are-same-or-not