# Python argparse compare input and default file names and types are same?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, argparse

```
def check_file(user_name,default_name):
    while True:
        try:
            #### check user name matches the default name
            if ('%s'%(user_name)) == '%s'%(default_name):
                print("file matches")
                break
        except:
            print("wrong file.")
            continue
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-k1',type=argparse.FileType('r'),default='k1file.txt',required=True,
                        help='file input')

    parser.add_argument('-k2',type=argparse.FileType('r'),default='k2file.txt',required=True,
                        help='file input')    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    check_file(args.k1,args.get_default('k1'))
    check_file(args.k2,args.get_default('k2'))
```

Present output:

```
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'k1'
```

Comment: When debugging include a `print(args)`, so you see what the parser has done, without any further assumptions or processing.  Off hand it looks like it should have a `k1` attribute, but I'd like to see the print to be sure.  What's that `args.get_default('k1')` supposed to do?  It doesn't look right.

Comment: @hpaulj I will try your suggestion for debugging. I wanted to compare the user input file with the default file? are the names the same? are both the same type?

Comment: Anyways, as the answer says, the `args` namespace object does not have access to the `default`.  That's an attribute of the `Action` object created by `add_argument`.  Why are you  expecting the user to enter the same thing as the default?  Just to make them jump-through-some-hoops?  Why `required` is True?

Comment: Another thing to watch out for.  The `default` is a string.  But with that `type`, the value in `args` will be an opened file.  They won't be equal.  That's yet another reason to print the `args`, to check on the value as well as name.  When new to a module, be careful about your assumptions.

Comment: Omit the `type` and just accept a filename string. You can open it later in a `with` context if it is right.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes! Maybe this would have caused the problem. I don't know but now the issue has been solved. Also, I solved the problem file name and type matching problem. I utilized the `choices` option in the `add_argument ['k1file.txt']` and this raises error if entered file is different than this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The `add_argument` method returns the `Action` that was just added. Which has details about the argument definition - including the default value.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

arg_action = parser.add_argument('-f', default='file')

print(arg_action.default)
```

Prints:

```
file
```

And you should be able to use that to compare the actual arguments with the default values.

Comment: but how do we compare the input with default? I am surprised why my code is throwing error.

Comment: Nothing wrong there. `args.k1` should give you the actual value. Check for typos in your code. I couldn't reproduce your issue.